# Clarification in a particular application of Le Chatelier principle

Tags: physical-chemistry, equilibrium

There is something I don't understand about a particular application of the Le Chatelier principle. The following system is in equilibrium: $$\ce{CH3COOH + H2O <=> H3O+ + CH3COO-}$$ If I add some $\ce{H3O+}$ the reaction will shift left. Now if I keep adding $\ce{H3O+}$, it will keep shifting left until the $\ce{CH3COO-}$ would deplete? And would the $\ce{H3O+}$ will remain at its initial concentration? So I can't understand how a buffer work, because if you have a reaction like above and you are adding acid, the added $\ce{H3O+}$ and the $\ce{CH3COO-}$ will bind together to form $\ce{CH3COOH}$ and water thus keeping the $\ce{H3O+}$ exactly the same. Where am I wrong?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/81192/why-doesnt-a-buffer-solution-change-phappreciably?rq=1

Comment: This question does not add any value for future visitors unless you clarify what was the need to bring in a buffer here, when the corresponding sodium ethanoate salt is not even present in the solution. Till then, I'm voting to close the question as unclear. You may always [edit] the question later to reflect changes.

Comment: @GaurangTandon There is no requirement of "sodium" for something to be a buffer.  Other spectator ions would do.  Why does OP need to include spectator ions to be understood?

Comment: @DavePhD Oh, I am sorry. I was about to write "metal ethanoate salt" or simply "ethanoate salt", but then substituted it with "sodium" for some reason. My fault. The reason why I said the question is unclear, instead, is that the OP says "The following system is in equilibrium:" but didn't ever say whether it was only acetic acid or acetic acid and its salt (only latter works). Moreover, the part after "So I can't understand how a buffer work..." simply wasn't clear. That said, I tried my best to answer the OP based on what I understood, and advised the OP to edit their question for clarity.

Comment: @GaurangTandon as long as there is some acetic acid and some acetate (some acid and some conjugate base) it is a buffer.  It don't think you should be distracted by the spectator ions, whether they be metal ions or quaternary amine ions or whatever.

Comment: @DavePhD Yes, I agree. There was no need to be distracted over the spectator ions.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I wouldn't classify your equilibrium as a buffer. A buffer requires excess weak acid, and it also requires either a strong base or the salt of the weak acid (which you don't have). The equilibrium you stated is the dissociation of CH<sub>3</sub>COOH into its conjugate base and a conjugate acid.

---

Say you had the following buffer:

$$CH_{3}COOH + NaOH ⇌ CH_{3}COONa + H_{2}O$$

The equilibrium of this would be:

$$CH_{3}COOH ⇌ CH_{3}COO^{-} + H^{+}$$

And the ionic equation would be:

$$H^{+} + OH^{-} → H_{2}O$$

As per definition, a buffer is a system that minimises pH change on small additions of acid or alkali. How? All down to equilibrium...

If you were to increase $[H^{+}]$:

- In terms of the equilibrium, the added $H^{+}$ would react with the base, $CH_{3}COO^{-}$, to form 
  $CH_{3}COOH$. This is Le Chatelier's principle in the fact that increasing $[H^{+}]$ shifts the equilibrium to the left.

If you were to increase $[OH^{-}]$:

- In terms of the ionic equation, the added $OH^{-}$ would react with the $H^{+}$ to form $H_{2}O$. This is Le Chatelier's principle in the fact that increasing $[OH^{-}]$ shifts the equilibrium to the right.

---

In both of these, it's clear that the addition of $H^{+}$ or $OH^{-}$ would just be an acid-base reaction. The products formed minimise the $pH$ of the system due to their relative strengths compared with the added acids/alkalis.

The $pH$ does change though, but just not as much as it would if it wasn't in the buffer system. A buffer just keeps the equilibrium central.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is good-intentioned but there are quite a few things that would need clarifying.

First, the above setup is not a buffer. You need additional metal ethanoate for a buffer to form. The above dissociation is only of a simple weak acid dissociating in water.

Secondly, yes, adding more $\ce{H3O+}$ to the above solution will shift the reaction to the left ("suppress the dissociation of acetic acid") but it would still **increase** the overall concentration of $\ce{H3O+}$, contrary to "the $\ce{H3O+}$ will remain at its initial concentration" (note that the backward shift is almost always negligible compared to the moles of hydronium we add (corrected thanks to @TanYongBoon!)).

If this doesn't make sense, consider waiting a bit more for your course work to proceed towards completion. Because sometimes, certain problems automatically clear themselves as you proceed later in the coursework :)